# Create Submit Error: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting an error

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

when trying to submit on a simple create page. Below is the controller code and model. I can not figure out what the issue is.

All fields except ID are nullable in SQL. I know that the issue is coming from the fields resolution and technician - if I put them on the create form (which they are not on it now as I do not want them filled out) the submit works fine Any ideas?

Thanks,
EB

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    HelpDesk b1 = new HelpDesk();
    return View(b1);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HelpDesk model)
{
    db.HelpDesks.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Model:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Requested By")]
public string RequestedBy { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Requested By Required.")]
public string Request { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Request Required.")]
public string Resolution { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Assigned To")]
public string Technician { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public string ModfiedBy { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: You are populating values in Request and Resolution property of the model object from the view? Check if the form had correct inputs bound to the correct model property and also that the form is submitting to the correct controller action. Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: What are those "EntityValidationErrors" telling you? Those typically contain the detailed information about which fields are causing errors......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All fields except ID is nullable in SQL.

That's not what you told Entity Framework, which is what's throwing the error.  (And, as the error indicates, you should really check the `EntityValidationErrors` property on the exception, or an inner exception, for specific information about the error.)  You told Entity Framework that these fields are required:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Requested By Required.")]
public string Request { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Request Required.")]
public string Resolution { get; set; }
```

(It looks like you may have mixed up some of the property attributes, judging by the messages on them.)

> I know that the issue is coming from the fields resolution and technician - if I put them on the create form (which they are not on it now as I do not want them filled out) the submit works fine

Sounds like that's the problem then.  `Resolution` is marked as required, and you're not including it.  Either include it or don't make it required.

Comment: @DavidL Yep. Overlooked that, Thanks!